# Strange javascript error

Tags: javascript

Well it's not realy causing any errors. Anyways i'm sending `ajax` request and getting back just some text then i split that text in array and finaly i just wanna do some checking so let's say this is how i do it:

```
var response = data.split("&&", 3); // here is my response and i split it by every &&

//now i wanna do some cheking if response isn't false
if(response[0] != 'false'){
   alert('it\'s not false');
}
```

And it always says that it's not false even thou it is, i've tried to `alert(response[0])` and i get `false` (btw it's just a string of text)

And i didn't include my full code here because it would make to much confusion, but i know it can't be error anywhere else since when i try to alert my `response[0]` i get `false` .

Comment: and what does this text look like? My crystal ball is in the shop for polishing today. Maybe it's an actual javascript boolean false, and not a literal string?

Comment: @Linas, when you `alert(response[0])`, are you getting `false` or something like `false `? Significant whitespace cannot easily be seen in an alert box, I'd suggest checking if `response[0].length` is indeed equal to `5`. Chances are it isn't.

Comment: it can't be an error anywhere else?
do you alert(data)?

Comment: What does `data` contain? People, OP is splitting a string, so `response[0]` is not going to be a bool -- it's going to be a string.

Comment: data also contains string with some text and little html, btw with `lenght` now i know that my string in fact is 6 characters long not 5 i just can't figure out where it comes from

Comment: @Linas: Sounds like there's a space either before or after the word 'false'. Try `alert("response[0] = '"+ response[0] +"'");`. That should make the space more obvious to see.

Comment: Or do a `response[0].replace(/\s/g, "") !== "false"` to remove whitespace before comparing

Comment: Well that's just srsly strange after doing what Travesty3 suguessted i got 
'
false' and if i look at firebug console i can't see any white spaces... and if i try to put white space before ` false` it doesn't work anyways

Comment: @Linas, wait, your question says `alert(response[0])` prints `false`, and now you're saying `alert("'" + response[0] + "'")` prints `' 0'`? That does not compute.

Comment: sorry i fixed it, i've just changed false to 0 to see if anything changes

Comment: Please post a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/. Hardcode the value of `data` as what you're expecting to get back from the ajax request.

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/Hb9MA/

Comment: @Linas, well, there *are* space characters around the `&&` operators in your string, and your `split()` call doesn't take them into account. If *all* your strings are like this one, you might want to split on `" && "` instead of `"&&"`. Otherwise, use Flambino's regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you seem to have spaces in the value that you're comparing to `false`.  Try this:

```
data.split( / *&& */, 3 );
```